# 504 error when trying to view results of contact report

Tags: civireport

first time asker here. Our resident Civi expert is out on sabbatical, so I'm coming to you with no developer knowledge to ask this support question.

My coworker is trying to create a contact report of all organizations in our database under the consulting industry. It all loads fine until they click "View results", then it just loads for ~5 minutes and times out giving them a 504 error.

Here's the page they get stuck at:
[image]

Here is the error page:
[image]

In case this is relevant, we are also experiencing long load times and sporadic timeouts when trying to load the CKEditor UI to browse images on the server in civimail.

We are using CiviCRM 5.58.1

Not sure if it's needed, but here are the alerts on our system status page:
[image]

Thanks so much in advance for your guidance with our issue!

John-Michael Torres
U.S. Federation of Worker Cooperatives

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your report isn't loading, hopefully your expert can figure that out after their sabbatical.

Meanwhile...

If all you need is a list of contacts of a certain type, there are many (arguably better) ways to do that without using CiviReport. Try looking in the Search menu for "Advanced Search" or try your hand at the latest and greatest tool, "Search Kit".

That's some general advice to your general question. If you want even better help on this site I recommend you edit your question to be more specific about what exactly you're trying to do (e.g. "I need to export mailing labels" or "I'm trying to create an end-of-year report and I need this data from CiviCRM") and then you'll get more specific advice about how to do it!